# Database config in multi module project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I separated my project into multiple modules, `core` is responsible for database access, business logic, etc.. Then there is also a module which provides a `graphql` API. The `graphql` module has `core` as its dependency but the configuration of the `application.yml` file in the `core` module doesn't seem to get loaded.

**Setup**

*Core - Application.class*

```
package project.core;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: core  # Identify this application
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project
    username: user
    password: something
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework:
      web: TRACE
      security: TRACE
```

*GRAPHQL Module - POM Dep*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*Application.class*

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"project.core", "project.graphql"})
public class ProjectGraphQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectGraphQL.class, args);
    }
}
```

Adding `core` to `@ComponentScan` fixed issues with JPA, but now I get the following error message.

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

What am I missing? I believe I could duplicate the configuration into my graphql configuration but I would rather keep all database stuff out of that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, where I tell the `graphql` application where to find the `application.properties` files (yml is not support with `@PropertySource`) and where to scan for `JpaRepositories` and `Entities`, defining the packages for `@ComponentScan` wasn't enough.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"core-application.properties", "application.properties"})
@ComponentScan({"project.core", "project.graphql"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("project.core")
@EntityScan("project.core")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ProjectGraphQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectGraphQL.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am not really happy with the additional configuration and switching to `.properties` over `.yml`, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix the modules this way. Spring Boot performs more things than only the component scan when running an application.

Keep the modules separate and use an application context hierarchy:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class ProjectGraphQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .parent(Application.class)
            .child(ProjectGraphQL.class)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```